# Am I allowed to ask the correct name for a specific feature?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I'm aware I cannot ask for recommendations and I'm not interested into.
But I'm looking for a specific feature of a 3D printer and since my primary language is not English I'm not sure which is the correct word (or words) to describe such a feature.

My question would be like this: "I'm looking for an enclosed 3D printer that allows to load a common 1 kg filament bobbin. Do these bobbins rely on a specific standard? How to filter out the printers that match my request when making a Google search?"

Is this question acceptable for you?

Comment: I think it's fine, with generic terms like that.

Comment: In general, I don't think this sort of question would have the problems that come with recommendation-type questions. (Recommendation questions tend to be very subjective in terms of what the best product is, and also tend to be time-specific in that product availability/prices/etc. often changes over time.) That said, whether it'd be a good question and whether the community wants to allow such questions may be a different matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Part identification is on topic

We have had questions about what the specs for a motor were, we had some about replacement parts.

### Spool sizes are on topic

**Bobbins, reels or spools** have almost standard sizes, because manufacturers buy them in bulk from China. Typical sizes I found looking on Alibaba (a website that connects manufacturers and wholesalers) are 0.33, 0.5, 0.75, 1 and 3 kg, most feature the same outer diameter but different spool widths, which allows easier packing. If there is a standard for those would be totally on topic.